# vb.net DatagridView Search using searchbox

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am getting "cannot find the column [Labels]" error even though the column is present in the datagridview. And here is my code. I am trying to load excel data to datagridview in vb.net.

```
Public Class Form1

Dim dbdataset1 As New DataTable

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Try

        Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim dataSet As System.Data.DataSet
        Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim path As String = "C:\Users\jtb43661\Downloads\Master_Bulletin_Flow of Funds.xls"

        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
        MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Admin$]", MyConnection)

        dataSet = New System.Data.DataSet
        MyCommand.Fill(dataSet)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0)

        MyConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    Dim dv As New DataView(dbdataset1)

    dv.RowFilter = String.Format("Labels Like '%{0}%'", TextBox1.Text)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dv

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: How's datagridview look like? How's is configured to display data for different columns? Where are you trying to access column "Labels" in your code? Which line is showing the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to filter via `dbdataset1` but that's not the same `DataTable` that you are populating and binding to the grid:

```
dataSet = New System.Data.DataSet
MyCommand.Fill(dataSet)
DataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0)
```

As you can see, no reference to `dbdataset1` there.

I would suggest changing your code significantly.  For a start, don't use misleading names for things.  For instance, `dbdataset1` might be a reasonable name for a variable of type `DataSet` but not if it's type `DataTable`.  As another example, `MyCommand` might be a reasonable name for an `OleDbCommand` variable but not for an `OleDbDataAdapter` variable.  You really ought to be consistent in your naming too, e.g. if you use `dataSet` and `path`, which are good names, then why use `MyConnection` and `MyCommand` rather than `connection` and `adapter` or `dataAdapter`?

More importantly though, you should get rid of both that `DataTable` field and the local `DataSet` variable and don't keep creating new `DataView` objects repeatedly.  Add a `BindingSource` to your form in the designer and then bind and filter through that.  This:

```
dataSet = New System.Data.DataSet
MyCommand.Fill(dataSet)
DataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0)
```

would become this:

```
Dim table As New DataTable

adapter.Fill(table)
BindingSource1.DataSource = table
DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
```

You would then filter like this:

```
BindingSource1.Filter = String.Format("Labels LIKE '%{0}%'", TextBox1.Text)
```

Here's how you might use a `Timer` as I suggest in my comment below:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    'Reset the Timer.
    Timer1.Stop()
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    'Apply the filter.
    BindingSource1.Filter = String.Format("SomeColumn LIKE '%{0}%'", TextBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot u made my day

Comment: I would further add that filtering on the `TextChanged` event is not ideal because that means that if the user wants to type multiple characters then they are forced to filter after each one, which is detrimental to performance. A better option is to use a `Timer` that you reset each time the user types a character and then you filter only when it raises a `Tick` event. You can set the `Interval` to something like 500 so that the filter happens quickly when the user finishes typing but not so quickly that it will happen between characters for all but the slowest typist. I'll add an example.

Comment: Hello jmcilhinney one more help, is it possible to search multiple keywords which is entered in the textbox1 ???
keywords will be separated with a comma(,) or anything? please help me

Comment: The filter is basically just a SQL WHERE clause and WHERE clauses support multiple conditions.  You simply need to split your keywords and then construct the appropriate WHERE clause, which would probably use 'OR' operators, e.g. `filter = String.Join(" OR ", keywords.Select(Function(s) String.Format("SomeColumn LIKE '%{0}%'", s)))`.

Comment: Thanks buddy u are awesome :)